# Does the nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient work with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, microsoft-data-sqlclient

My application runs on .NET framework 4.7 and I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3. Currently, my code uses some classes from the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient` such as `SqlParameter`. I want to switch to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

However, I'm not sure if EF6 is compatible with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. This is an old [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) from Microsoft, it says that EF Core, EF 6 etc. haven’t yet made the transition to the new provider `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. So, I'm a bit confused.

Everything has been working well with `System.Data.SqlClient` for the below code

```
public async Task<ICollection<int>> GetChildCustomerIdsAsync(int customerId)
{
   var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
   {
      new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", customerId)
   };

   return await DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("dbo.sp_GetChildCustomerIds @CustomerId=@CustomerId",
                sqlParameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

However, when I am switching to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object value)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.AddRange(Array values)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternalAsync.d__6f`1.MoveNext()

Comment: That article is still correct for EF6. You can't combine `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` with Entity Framework (unless you take care to keep classes strictly separated, I suppose). Recent versions of EF Core *have* switched to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, though.

Comment: Did you try add parameter without @ just  new SqlParameter("CustomerId", customerId) ?

Comment: @IvanMartinyuk Removing @ from the parameter name didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, EF 6 does not work with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, but I have published a package that does.

NuGet package: [ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer)

Documentation: [here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework6PowerTools/tree/community/src/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer) and [here](https://erikej.github.io/ef6/sqlserver/2021/08/08/ef6-microsoft-data-sqlclient.html)

Comment: Thank you @ErikEJ for the clarification. Could you please also tell me if there is any workaround to make the above code work or what would be the recommended approach to switch to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in my application.

Comment: If anyone needs more information about this, it can be found on https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/725.

Comment: This issue is the actual issue for MDS support in EF6: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/823

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is planning it

https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/823#issuecomment-948340657

> We're planning for next year now, and so far this is tentatively in the plan.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#theme-clear-path-forward-from-ef6

> The exception to this is that we plan to add support for using EF6
> with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. This will be limited to runtime
> support. Use of the EF6 designer in Visual Studio will still require
> System.Data.SqlClient.

---

In the meantime, you can try adding a provider created by ErikEJ. This should help.

NuGet package: [ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer)

Documentation: [here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework6PowerTools/tree/community/src/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer) and [here](https://erikej.github.io/ef6/sqlserver/2021/08/08/ef6-microsoft-data-sqlclient.html)

---

Microsoft has accepted ErikEJ's [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/pull/2063).

NuGet package: [Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer) (*release is pending*)

Documentation: [here](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/tree/main/src/Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer)